# Range filter doesn't accept variables

Tags: templating, filter, plugin-supertable, range

How do I pass variables into the range filter from a static supertable field?

```
{% for item in variants.b2bProductQty %}

  {% set start = item.selectRange.cellStartInteger %}
  {% set end = item.selectRange.cellEndInteger %}
  {% set increment = item.selectRange.cellIncerement %}

  {% for i in range(start, end, increment) %}
     <option value="{{ variants.sku }}:">{{ i }}</option>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

This results in the error:

> range(): Argument #3 ($step) must not exceed the specified range

When I hardcode the numbers from the field it works

```
{% for i in range(5, 50, 5) %}
   <option value="{{ variants.sku }}:">{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

If I just print out `{{ start }}` it shows `5` just fine

Comment: could it be that you have a typo? "cellIncerement" instead of "cellIncrement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the increment variable because it is optional. If there is no value it throws an error it shoudl default to `1`

So I constructed it like this:

```
{% for item in variants.b2bProductQty %}

  {% set start = item.rangeStart %}
  {% set end = item.rangeEnd %}
  {% set increment = item.rangeInc ? item.rangeInc : 1 %} {# fallback to 1 #}
                                
  {% for i in range( item.rangeStart , item.rangeEnd, increment) %}
    <option value="{{ variants.sku }}:">{{ i }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
                                
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test easily because I never use Supertable, but my guess would be that if you were to dump out `item.selectRange.cellStartInteger` (DUMP out, not just print out - ie.`{{ dump(item.selectRange.cellStartInteger) }}`), you might find that it's a big complicated object rather than just a simple value. In that case, if it's anything like Craft's dropdown field you'll need to put `.value` on the end to get just the raw value.

Comment: You are correct. The dump outputs `int(5)`

I switched back to regular integer fields but this outputs the same. How do I only get `5` ?

Comment: Well, no... `int(5)` means I'm not correct here. It's not a big complicated object as I was guessing - this means it's a simple integer, as it should be.